# Apply function for use with a embeded conditional expression that includes objects

Tags: r

I have a conditional expression (example) as follows

```
g1<-function(list (m1), iter=1000L)

M1<-if (!exists("m1")) {0
} else if (is.na(m1$results$RMSE[1])){0
} else if (!exists(g1)){0
} else {m1
}
```

So M1 yields either 0 or m1, (m1 and g1 are two objects). This conditional expression is repeated 85 times for m2...m85 and g2...g85 yielding M1...M85.

m1...m85 and g1...g85 are all objects.

I would like to eliminate the repetitions as to obtain M1...M85 by means of a single expression yielding the outcome for M1...M85.

Have tried with apply without luck. I can not come out with the correct syntaxis to put the conditional expression as a function. How can I use apply given that m and g are objects and can not be placed in a matrix, dataframe etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. It will return a list with 85 elements.

```
n <- 1:85
m <- paste0("m", n)
g <- paste0("g", n)

mapply(function(mi, gi) {
  if (!exists(mi) || is.na(get(mi)$results$RMSE[1]) || !exists(gi))
    0
  else
    get(mi)
}, m, g)
```